# Asp.net encrypt sqlConnectionString in sessionState

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-state

I am using sessionState mode = "SQLServer" in my application. Is there any way to encrypt the connection string that was passed in web.config?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To encrypt sql server connection between applications you can just add

```
encrypt=true
```

to the connection string, eg:

```
"Server=##.##.##.##,1092;Database=dbname;uid=username;pwd=password;encrypt=true"
```

To encrypt the string in web.config see [how-to-encrypt-connection-string-in-web.config](http://geekswithblogs.net/jeroenb/archive/2011/06/08/how-to-encrypt-connection-string-in-web.config.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I was in the same position and I also couldn't find any answer. The accepted answer also doesnt reciprocate the question asked in my opinion. After some research, i did the following to solve the issue and encrypted the `sessionState` node having `connectionString` of web.config

**Encryption:**

You can follow the following steps to encrypt a specific section of web.config:

- Run command prompt as an `administrator`
- Execute the command:

  ```
   cd C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
  ```
- Execute the command:

`ASPNET_REGIIS -pef "system.web/sessionState" "PhysicalPathOfWebsiteThatHasWebConfigFile"`

**Decryption:**

Similarly if you want to decrypt a specific node in the web.config, follow the same above steps and replace `-pef` with `-pdf` in the final step and the utility will decrypt the specific node

**Explanation about above commands:**

1. `ASPNET_REGIIS`: Taken from official [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/zhhddkxy(v=vs.100)), You can use the ASP.NET IIS Registration Tool (Aspnet_regiis.exe) to encrypt or decrypt sections of a Web configuration file. ASP.NET will automatically decrypt encrypted configuration elements when the Web.config file is processed. And -pef tells that you want to use it for encrypting a specific section in your web.config. It serves other purposes as well as explained in the official [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-2.0/k6h9cz8h(v=vs.80)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
2. `system.web/sessionState` is the specific node that you want to encrypt.
3. `PhysicalPathOfWebsiteThatHasWebConfigFile` is the physical path of your application (where web.config is located). Please do not add an extra ‘\’ at the end of the path.

**Other Reference Links:**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/zhhddkxy(v=vs.100)

[What does aspnet_regiis.exe do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538870/what-does-aspnet-regiis-exe-do)